# Number of distinct remainders modulo n smaller than Euler's totient function

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function, multiplicative-order

How come that the number of distinct remainders $a_{k}$ for $g^{k}\equiv a_{k} \mod (n)$ for specific positive $n$ and any positive $g$ and $k=1,2,3...$ is never greater than $\varphi (n)$ (Euler's totient function)?

Example $n=6$:

For $g=2$ 
$$2^{1} \equiv 2 \mod (6)$$
$$2^{2} \equiv 4 \mod (6)$$
$$2^{3} \equiv 2 \mod (6)$$
For $g=3$
$$3^{1} \equiv 3 \mod (6)$$
$$3^{2} \equiv 3 \mod (6)$$
For $g=4$
$$4^{1} \equiv 4 \mod (6)$$
$$4^{2} \equiv 4 \mod (6)$$
For $g=5$
$$5^{1} \equiv 5 \mod (6)$$
$$5^{2} \equiv 4 \mod (6)$$
$$5^{3} \equiv 5 \mod (6)$$
For $g=11$
$$11^{1} \equiv 5 \mod (6)$$
$$11^{2} \equiv 1 \mod (6)$$
$$11^{3} \equiv 5 \mod (6)$$
$$...$$

The number of distinct remainders is never greater than $\varphi(6) = 2$.

Comment: yes, this is because $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\times)$ is a group with $\varphi(n)$ elements, so whenever $g$ is inversible modulo $n$ :  $order_n(g) \le \varphi(n)$. Now if $g$ is not inversible, then ...

Comment: @user, some of the elements Lukas is asking about aren't in that group. In some of the examples, $g$ is not relatively prime to the modulus.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes I edited my comment. for example $2^3 \equiv 2 \bmod 6$, in that case we have to look at $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $\varphi(3) = 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) and the fact that [$\varphi$ is multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), you need only consider the case when $n = p^{t}$ is the power of a prime $p$.

In this case, if $p \nmid g$, the result is clear, as $g$ lies in the group of invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z} / p^{t} \mathbb{Z}$, of size $\varphi(p^{t})$.

If $p \mid g$, then $g^{t} = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z} / p^{t} \mathbb{Z}$, so the number of distinct remainders $g^{k}$ is at most $$t \le p^{t-1} \le (p -1) p^{t-1} = \varphi(p^{t}),$$ as $$p^{t-1} = (1 + (p-1))^{t-1} \ge 1 + (t-1)(p-1) \ge 1 + t - 1 = t.$$

Comment: I don't think he gets the multiplicative part. Do you have an elementary argument for reducing the general case to the $n = p^t$ case ?

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for your answer. I will mark it as correct. Just for clarification: for general case $n\neq p^{t}$ can we use what I have found about [multiplicative group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) that for general case $n=p_{1}^{k_{1}}p_{2}^{k_{2}}...$ we have a direct product of rings corresponding to the prime factors $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/p_{1}^{k_{1}}\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p_{2}^{k_{2}}\mathbb{Z}...$? Could you please help me with what is the meant by the **direct product**?

Comment: @LukášČerný, absolutely, this is what I meant by quoting the Chinese remainder theorem. Direct product means that you do the ring operations by components - for instance the sum is very much the same as the sum of $n$-tuples of real numbers, say, that pops up when doing vector spaces.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti ok, and specifically for example $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If you denote congruence classes as $[a]_{5}, [a]_{7}$, you have $([a_{1}]_{5}, [b_{1}]_{7}) + ([a_{2}]_{5}, [b_{2}]_{7}) = ([a_{1}]_{5} + [a_{2}]_{5}, [b_{1}]_{7} + [b_{2}]_{7}) = ([a_{1} + a_{2}]_{5}, [b_{1} + b_{2}]_{7})$ and $([a_{1}]_{5}, [b_{1}]_{7}) \cdot ([a_{2}]_{5}, [b_{2}]_{7}) = ([a_{1}]_{5} \cdot [a_{2}]_{5}, [b_{1}]_{7} \cdot [b_{2}]_{7}) = ([a_{1} \cdot a_{2}]_{5}, [b_{1} \cdot b_{2}]_{7})$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti perfect! thank you